# When debugging an ASP.NET MVC app, how can I get my changes to Site.css to show up?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I'm debugging on my development machine and when I make changes to the css file, they don't show up and I can't figure out why.  I'm using firebug and inspecting the css and the changes are not there. I've tried clear private data and building the project first then running it but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the path to the CSS file from your code?  I'm wondering if it is hard-coded to something other than the local machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **CTL+F5** to force a full refresh -- it will force the browser to ignore anything cached.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caching your css file. Either modify your setting in the browser to stop caching, or add a unique identifier to the css file like Site.css?d=011509.

Comment: I think this works well in production, but the id would have to have a granularity too fine for normal production use to useful for development.